# How to set environment variable for build time in CMake?

Tags: python, build, cmake

I have a python script that generates *.cpp* sources that are used in consequent compilation. The script uses some 3rd-party modules, and I'm trying to set `PYTHONPATH` to modules location.

I tried to do `set(ENV${PYTHONPATH} "/path/to/modules")`, but unfortunately it works only for generation time i.e. `execute_process(COMMAND python the_script.py)`, while I need it to work for `add_custom_command/add_custom_target`.

I am using *Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64* generator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [CMake's Command-Line Tool Mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html):

```
add_custom_command(
    ... 
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env PYTHONPATH="/path/to/modules" python the_script.py
)
```